# Change the displayed shipping method title in WooCommerce checkout based on product shipping class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I am trying to figure out how to change the shipping method title displayed in WooCommerce checkout of my store based on the shipping class the product has. I have multiple shipping classes for example, 3-day shipping, freight, and standard shipping, for the rate classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Based on [Woocommerce Change shipping method title on checkout based on shipping class selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026568/woocommerce-change-shipping-method-title-on-checkout-based-on-shipping-class-sel/51028322#51028322) answer code, I tried pasting the following code **(customized with my settings)**:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_shipping_method_name_based_on_shipping_class', 50, 2);
function change_shipping_method_name_based_on_shipping_class($rates, $package){
    // HERE set the shipping class for "Standard Flate Rate"
    $shipping_class_id = 64;
    $found = false;

    // Check for the "Standard Flate Rate" shipping class in cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_id ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Loop through shipping methods
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Change "Flat rate" Shipping method label name
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
            if( $found )
                $rates[$rate_key]->label = __( 'Standard Flate Rate', 'woocommerce' );
            else
                $rates[$rate_key]->label = __( '3 Day Shipping', 'woocommerce' );

                $rates[$rate_key]->label = __( 'Freight', 'woocommerce' );
               
                $rates[$rate_key]->label = __( 'standard Shipping', 'woocommerce' );

        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to define the correct shipping class ID for  `$shipping_class_id` variable. Also on the `else`you can only have one defined `$rates[$rate_key]->label`. Also is better to use brackets `{` and `}` for the `IF` / `ELSE`statements, something like: `if( $found ) { $rates[$rate_key]->label = 'yes'; } else { $rates[$rate_key]->label = 'no'; }`... This code can`t work with 3 shipping classes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there an way to make 3 classes  work correctly in the form i need it to work any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This can not work if you have 2 cart items with different shipping classes…